# LaTeX to HTML preserving code coloring from listings

Tags: listings, tex4ht, htlatex

I'm trying to convert some LaTeX into HTML but my code listings don't preserve their code coloring. Why is that and how do I fix it?

This is what it looks like:

[image]

Side note: I'm also wondering why the caption on the table was removed.

**Edit**

Here is an example listing with colors:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
    basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
    language=[Sharp]C, 
    keywordstyle=\color[rgb]{0,0,1.0}\bfseries,  
    commentstyle=\color[rgb]{0.133,0.545,0.133}\bfseries,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
int x = 10;

// This is a comment
string str = "hello";
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

This produces the following HTML when doing: `htlatex myfile.tex`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"  
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">  
<html > 
<head><title></title> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"> 
<meta name="generator" content="TeX4ht (http://www.cse.ohio-state.edu/~gurari/TeX4ht/)"> 
<meta name="originator" content="TeX4ht (http://www.cse.ohio-state.edu/~gurari/TeX4ht/)"> 
<!-- html --> 
<meta name="src" content="LaTeX4.tex"> 
<meta name="date" content="2012-07-20 12:30:00"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="LaTeX4.css"> 
</head><body 
>
   <!--l. 12-->
   <div class="lstlisting" id="listing-1"><span class="label"><a 
 id="x1-2r1"></a></span><span 
class="cmtt-8">int</span><span 
class="cmtt-8">&#x00A0;</span><span 
class="cmtt-8">x</span><span 
class="cmtt-8">&#x00A0;</span><span 
class="cmtt-8">=</span><span 
class="cmtt-8">&#x00A0;</span><span 
class="cmtt-8">10;</span><span 
class="cmtt-8">&#x00A0;</span><br /><span class="label"><a 
 id="x1-3r2"></a></span><span 
class="cmtt-8">&#x00A0;</span><br /><span class="label"><a 
 id="x1-4r3"></a></span><span 
class="cmtt-8">//</span><span 
class="cmtt-8">&#x00A0;</span><span 
class="cmtt-8">This</span><span 
class="cmtt-8">&#x00A0;</span><span 
class="cmtt-8">is</span><span 
class="cmtt-8">&#x00A0;</span><span 
class="cmtt-8">a</span><span 
class="cmtt-8">&#x00A0;</span><span 
class="cmtt-8">comment</span><span 
class="cmtt-8">&#x00A0;</span><br /><span class="label"><a 
 id="x1-5r4"></a></span><span 
class="cmtt-8">string</span><span 
class="cmtt-8">&#x00A0;</span><span 
class="cmtt-8">str</span><span 
class="cmtt-8">&#x00A0;</span><span 
class="cmtt-8">=</span><span 
class="cmtt-8">&#x00A0;</span><span 
class="cmtt-8">"</span><span 
class="cmtt-8">hello</span><span 
class="cmtt-8">"</span><span 
class="cmtt-8">;</span>

   </div>

</body></html>
```

Which looks like this:

[image]

I would want the HTML result to look like this:

[image]

Comment: A minimal example would helpful. For example: what are you using to colour the code? What are you using to do the conversion?

Comment: @Seamus, Sure, Updated my question.

Comment: **I do not** want to specify Each keyword that I want colored manually!

Comment: See this discussion at the tex4ht mailing list: http://tug.org/pipermail/tex4ht/2010q4/000243.html

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, I've read that but it doensn't work with Listings.

Comment: Did you read the complete thread of the discussion? At the end Radhakrishnan discuss listings and even did attach some files.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, Yeah, I tried his examples and it didn't add colors to my listings. He only changes all test color to green and background to black, no keyword highlighting.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is perhaps possible to hook somewhere in the `listings` commands so that they write sensible class instructions. But on the other side `listings` is very complicated and this could easily break. Imho a more simple approach is with fonts: if every style is connected to a different font then `tex4ht` surrounds the chars with classes which you can set throught css. Here an example (it runs only with `htlatex`, if you want to use `pdflatex` you will have to move the `\Css` to a configuration file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\lstset{
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    language=[Sharp]C,
    keywordstyle=\rmfamily\bfseries,
    commentstyle=\sffamily,
}
\def\mystyle{}


\begin{document}

\Css{div.lstlisting .ectt-1000 {font-family: monospace;color:blue}}
\Css{div.lstlisting .ecss-1000 {font-family: monospace;color:green}} 
\Css{div.lstlisting .ecbx-1000 {font-family: monospace;color:red}} 


\section{Test!}

{\ttfamily hello}, {\sffamily Hello} {\bfseries Hello}


\begin{lstlisting}
int x = 10;

// This is a comment
string str = "hello";
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That looks very interesting! I'll try that, thanks! Another question that just arised from this is, what if I have `\newenvironment{myEnv}` and I want a specific class for this, is there an easy way to do that? I tried `\ConfigureEnv{myEnv}{\HCode{<div class="myEnv">}}{\HCode{</div>}}{}{}` but it doesn't seem to wrap around my environment. No worries regarding pdflatex, I'm using 2 different tex-files and just including the "raw" stuff and doing all the configs/definitiouns outside :)

Comment: You must also define the hooks. See http://www.cvr.cc/tex4ht-low-level-commands/

Comment: Ok! Do you think you could help me out with an example of what it would looke like for when I do `\begin{myEnv}test\end{myEnv}`?  One last thing that I'm noticing is that I'm getting a lot of errors regarding my own environments and on figures, looks somewhat like this: http://pastebin.com/9eGGbP2g have you got any idea why that is?

Comment: Actually simply `\ConfigureEnv{myEnv}{\HCode{<div class="myEnv">}}{\HCode{</div>}}{}{}` (after `\begin{document}`) works fine for me (I had a typo in my first test). So you should perhaps make an example (and open a new question). Same for your error message. I have no idea where e.g. the `\FBafil` comes from.

Comment: I'm not doing any `\FBafil` myself, so it's probably through some macro or something. It just bothers me that I have to hold my `Enter` key for 1 minute to accept all errors. I'll open a new question later, thanks. I'll mark your answer as accepted in a couple of days to let more people contribute with answers, if that is OK.