# How can I make bash-code look good both in LaTeX and HTML?

Tags: verbatim, html, htlatex, bash

As I am new to Latex and this kind of typing in general, I find myself in need of some basic guidelines when it comes to how to make things look good in text. I have a document that looks good when typeset into a .pdf, but when I compile it to .html using `htlatex` the text loses its color, making it more difficult to distinguish from the surrounding text.

How can I write bash text so that it looks good when compiled into an html-file? Is there a commonly used method that makes bash look good?

Right now I use an environment every time:

```
\newenvironment{vtim}
{\color{magenta}
\begin{tt}
\fontsize{11pt}{11pt}\selectfont}
{\end{tt}}
```

And then, when I want bash in text:

```
\begin{vtim}
\$ Text text text text text
\end{vtim}
```

Comment: You should look into the [`listings`](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings) package. You will likely still lose the color, but you could then check out [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/64054/17423).

Comment: @SeanAllred Should I do any modifications to the listings font, to make it look "better"?

Comment: Many people prefer a monospaced font for code, but the default font does not have bolded variants. Thus, I personally use something like this: https://gist.github.com/95ea52de7399beb2fa8e.  Note that it must be compiled with XeLaTeX (or LuaLaTeX, I suppose).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For `pdf` output you can use the `minted` package. This produces a nicely formatted and coloured PDF file for you.

As described in the `minted` package documentation, you have to install `Pygments` and run (pdf)latex with the `-shell-escape` option. To use this approach to produce `html` you also need to pass the `-shell-scape` option to `htlatex`. You can do this using

> htlatex file.tex "" "" "" -shell-escape

Note that the three double quotes `"" "" ""` are necessary as the `-shell-escape` has to be the *fifth* option to `htlatex`.

Running `htlatex` on my MWE below gives the following html output:

[image: HTML output]

I was going to put up two images but, as far as I can tell, the PDF and HTML output are identical.

Finally, here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\begin{document}
\begin{minted}{c}
#!/bin/sh
# removes backup files and TeX files

if [ $# -gt 0 ] && [ $1 = "-b" ]
then
    shift
    backups=false
else
    backups=true
fi

...
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

Btw, I just learnt that `minted` also has a very useful command:

```
\inputminted[⟨options⟩]{⟨language⟩}{⟨filename⟩}
```

You can use this to typeset your source code without physically including it in your tex document.